# SQL Agent runs procedure to send email with success but email doesn't arrive

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-agent-job

Basically I have a SQL JOB that runs a procedure responsible for executing a query and sending an email with `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`, when I run the procedure, works as intended and the email is delivered. But when I created a job in the SQL Agent, the jos runs with success but no email is delivered.

The procedure in question is this one:

```
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'Active_users',  
    @recipients = 'teste0@teste.com;teste1@teste.com',  
    @subject = 'List',
    @body = 'Users',
    @query = 'SELECT Top 1000 
       [caller_id]
      ,[session_start_dt]
      ,[session_end_dt]
      ,[caller_address]
      ,[caller_type]
  FROM [database].[db].[teste1]
  where session_end_dt IS NULL
  order by caller_id desc' ,
   @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
   @query_attachment_filename = 'users.csv',
   @query_result_header = 1,
   @query_result_no_padding = 1,
   @exclude_query_output = 1;
```

My first though was a permissions issue that the user `SQLAgtAct` didnt had acess to the database in question, but it has and has the role of `db_datareader`, `db_datawriter`, `db_ddladmin`.
I don't know if the user SQLAgtAct needs any more permissons, than this ones, since the job runs with sucess.

Comment: Does the SQL Server Agent Service account have the `DatabaseMailUserRole` role and is the `Active_users` profile public, or does it [the service account] have permission to send emails from that profile?

Comment: Did you look at `msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log`?

Comment: Also look at the agent job history to see if there are errors.